# org.apache.commons.codec.binary.Base32 decodes to same byte array for different strings

Tags: java, base32

I have a encoded String and trying to decode it.
But I am getting the same `byte[]` when I added zeros into it.

```
String val = "VU4ACWPU52WWBTKV4PLCC6BQPA5E7ZLYITGR4NLIZKYZKPPZU2SPZYQPECFA6SCIOYQTU4P4XFERESTTXUSOM4BBZYARDBKHDIGZFPWQ";

Base32 base32 = new Base32(0);

base32.decode(val);
base32.decode("000"+ val);
```

Both the decodes above returns the same byte array. Can anyone help me understand whys is it same when I added some zeros to it? Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Look here:

https://guava.dev/releases/16.0/api/docs/com/google/common/io/BaseEncoding.html

You can see that base32 is using A-Z and 2-7 as encoding. Zeros will not change anything.

Comment: Are these the same library? Mine is the apache library

Comment: It has the same functionality. Look at row 56 up until 82: https://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-codec/jacoco/org.apache.commons.codec.binary/Base32.java.html

Comment: got it. Thanks. I think I should pick the hex encode/decode

Comment: changed Base32 base32 = new Base32(0); to Base32 base32 = new Base32(true); worked